# How to place a marker on Google Maps and saving to database?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit

Basically, the location data will be in database and when I open the app, the app retrieves data from database and show them on maps. Also, when it's clicked, it gives the direction from my location to that location. I'm using retrofit for membership system. Can I do that with retrofit?

Like JustPark application if you know.

How can I implement that?

Comment: Retrofit is useful for REST API calls. I am not sure what do you mean by "Can I do that with retrofit?"

Comment: I mean saving that data with retrofit

Comment: you can do anything from the data you receive from Retrofit. Retrofit will not help you save it. It will just do the REST API call for you and return the results probably in a JSON Array. Then its upto you how to handle it